# Slick2D Music Trouble

Tags: java, audio, slick2d

I'm new to Slick2D, LWJGL, etc. Anyway I've been trying to make a simple in-game menu when pressing the escape button. Everything works fine, however when I hit the escape button I would like the current music to pause and play a sound when the menu opens. Then for the music to continue when the menu closes. However when I do hit escape it works the sound plays and the music stops, but when I hit escape again the music doesn't resume. Any suggestions?

```
if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
        //Toggles Menu Open/Close
        inGameMenu = !inGameMenu;

        //Toggle Music to shut off
        pauseMusic = !pauseMusic;

        //Opacity trick
        InGameMenu.resetOpacity = !InGameMenu.resetOpacity;

        //toggle menu open/close
        InGameMenu.closeMenu = !InGameMenu.closeMenu;

        if(pauseMusic){
            if(Sound.bgMusic.playing()){
                Sound.bgMusic.pause();
            } 
                ObjectSounds.menuOpen.play();

        } else {
            if(ObjectSounds.menuOpen.playing()) {
                ObjectSounds.menuOpen.stop();
            }
            if(!Sound.bgMusic.playing())
                Sound.bgMusic.play();
        }

        System.out.println(pauseMusic);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Music is its own dedicated audio channel, but there is Sound which is another.